# magic/eDeveloper/uniPaaS: How to allow space character as range in a model?

Tags: magic-unipaas

In uniPaaS I have a model (*Attribute=Alpha*; *Picture=1*) with *Range=J,N*. 
That allows the users to insert only J or N into an edit field using that model.
But now I have to change the range property of that model, so that a user also can type a space to that input field. Also it should be possible to leave the input field empty.

I tried the following as Range, but nothing works:

```
J,,N
J, ,N
J,' ',N
J," ",N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space character must be the first in the list, so the following string works as Range property.

```
" ,J,N"  (without the quotes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the Picture of your model. Since the picture of your variable/column is only 1, only 1 character can your container be handled.
The obvious solution is to extend the variable Picture to your desired value it can hold.

From your example you can change the picture to 10 since you will be inputting the following values.

J,,N
J, ,N
J,' ',N
J," ",N

That way, it can handle values less than or equal to 10 characters.
Hope this helped.

Comment: The problem was the Range (range of valid values) and not the Picture. The picture must be 1, because there is only one char allowed.